# Generics arguments inference in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am studying generics in Typescript and according the rules we can create something like this:

```
function identity<Type>(arg: Type): Type {
  return arg;
}

identity(123)
```

According TS [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) the compiler will infer the value that is passed in `identity` function, without doing `identity<number>(123)`. In our case there is a number. 
 I just want to understand how TS works in this case:

Question:  It infers the `args` according to this type `arg: Type` or this one `identity<Type>`?

Comment: Since you are using the <Type> as the type parameter and the type of the argument, typescript is smart to understand that whatever value you pass as argument, it's type will be the generic type.

Comment: obviously to `arg: Type` since you don't call the function like `identity<number>(123)` ... if you call the function like `identity<string>(123)` it will throw an error because the `Type` is set as a string before it is infered as a number by args

Comment: I'm not sure what this question means; could you clarify? You need the type parameter to appear in both places for the inference to make sense, so it infers "according to" *both*, depending on what "according to" means.  What would it mean to you for it to infer from just one place? If I asked you: "John is 75 years old. John is my father. How old is my father?", *would you answer that according to the first or the second instance of the word "John"?*